# A query ranking users by number of badges per class - like the user card

Tags: feature-request, badges, data-explorer

I wanted a query that would rank users by total count of badges per class. That is, a ranking like the user card; with 3 columns: gold, silver, bronze - having the total counts (and possibly with the total reputation rank number in the first column).

I tried to search the existing posts tagged with [[tag:data-explorer] and [tag:badges]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer+badges), but the closest available queries don't give results as I described.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two queries I made some time ago. And I have added two more which also have some info on the reputation of those users.

- [Most gold, silver, bronze badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/976394/most-gold-silver-bronze-badges)
- [Most gold, silver, bronze tag badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1060793/most-gold-silver-bronze-tag-badges)
- [Most gold, silver, bronze badges (including info on reputation)](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1367282/most-gold-silver-bronze-badges-including-info-on-reputation)
- [Most gold, silver, bronze tag badges  (including info on reputation)](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1367285/most-gold-silver-bronze-tag-badges-including-info-on-reputation)

Comment: Rank in the first column doesn't coincide with order by number total number of badges? I don't understand why but those 2 columns should reflect each other.

Comment: Ah OK, rank in the first column is sorted by gold badge count.

Answer (score 2):

As a technology demonstration I share [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1367707/most-gold-silver-bronze-badges?num=200) that uses the [PIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) feature of SQL Server. It turns out the Badges table is perfect to use. The resulting query isn't necessarily easier to grasp then the one offered by Martin.

```
select TOP(##num?200##)
       rank() over(order by [1]+[2]+[3] desc) [rank] -- and ranking functions works
     , UserId as [User Link]  -- we pivot over this column
     , [1] [Gold]    -- first value column
     , [2] [Silver]  -- 2nd value column
     , [3] [Bronze]  -- 3rd value column
     , [1]+[2]+[3] [total]  -- \o/ we can calc as well
from (
  -- this is the main resultset 
  select id
       , Userid
       , class
  from badges
) data
pivot 
(
  count(id) -- aggregate count can work here
  FOR 
  class in ([1], [2], [3]) -- each value in 'class' becomes a column
) pvt
order by [1]+[2]+[3] desc
```

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).